# Maximum number of rows to display in a table on a web page?

Tags: gridview

When generating a table of data on a web page, I usually give the user the option to page through the data (10, 25, 50, 100 rows per page) or to display it all on one page. This works fine for a few hundred rows, but displaying thousands of rows on one page can take a long time to generate and transmit to the browser.

Is there a rule of thumb or a best practice for determining the maximum number of rows to display in a table on one page? I.e. when is it best to suppress the option to display all rows and force the user to page?

Comment: Also think about the twitter style "More" instead of paging ... at least I am for my next project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"When performance suffers" would be my answer, which you need to decide via testing (on the slowest and crappiest browser; IE6).

If the user needs the data as a whole you can always offer it up as a CSV download.

Answer (score 2):

You should really do a full usage analysis on the page in question.  Find out what your users really need.

For example:

Do they really need to see all of the records (thousands) on the screen at once or do they just need better filtering tools to get the subset they want.

If they need all the records, do they need it on the page or would a "export" button which creates a CSV file be a better route?

Comment: The users usually filter down to a few hundred or less, then they choose to display all, or just page (which is the default). They have an export to CSV button for when they need all the records in one place as a report. They don't really need to see thousands of records on a page at once.

Comment: @noj: In that case it sounds like you are doing the right thing.

Comment: Except that some folk choose to display thousands on the screen just because they can, usually with terrible performance. So I really need to take away the display all option and limit the number of records they can display on the screen at once.

Comment: @noj: Ok.  I'm failing to see the problem here.  Either you allow them to do this or you don't.  Every app is different in this regard.  If your users demand to list thousands of records, then let them.  They'll learn soon enough that it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an application where it has allowed me to set a page size of more than 100 items per page.  Anything beyond that and performance will degrade (if it hasn't already degraded somewhere before 100 records).  It depends on what you're displaying, whether there are images to be loaded, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Watch it here, on StackOverflow: when you browse questions, you don't have an option to display all questions. Otherwise you would have to wait for a very looooooong time. Consider not to give the user such an opportunity at all.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps find out how your users will use your application and design accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Think "findability". Google can show only say the top 10 links on a page because you're very likely to find the right what you're looking for. On the other hand, if you're browsing a site like newegg.com with a limited universe of items that are best grouped by categories - i.e. computer products - the faceted navigation is often a better means of drilling through the options as opposed to search.

In a general sense I find the number of results is best kept at a size that requires no more than two full screen sizes to scroll through (yes I know resolutions differ). From there provide pagination, but with the ability to skip pages, and if possible with a total number of pages.

Comment: A 'screenfull' is about 40 records at the typical settings of our users. A max of 80 records per page seems a bit low?

Comment: How likely is it that your users will find the answer they're looking for in those 1st 80 rows?

Comment: Well, if they are looking for one specific thing they can usually find it right away through the filter options. But I'm thinking more about applications where the user is interested in each of the results they get back - e.g. monitoring reports where they want to see all the students that have an overdue assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on the end goal.  I know of no "rule of thumb".

I display over 10000 rows in one application on a single page and the user can select the data and move it where they want. Takes less than 15 seconds to display.  Most are only seeing 10-100 per page, but some datasets are very large.

You can display a limited number of records (i.e. Select TOP X * from table) and then provide a system for the next X number of rows OR

You can display all records and let the user decide how they want to use the data.  One of the ideas already presented would also be to provide a method to download the data and let the user decide on how they would like to use it.